# Contact Form with ReactJS don't sends data to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mdbreact

I'm new to ReactJS and I was building an application with Firebase in which I'm facing a weird scenario, lemme explain.

```
sendtofirebase()
{
    db.collection('contacts').add({
        name:'faizam',
        email:'shdj',
        subject:'hdjshj',
        message:'hjhdjs',
    }).then(()=>{
    alert("Data Sent");
    }).catch((error)=>{
        alert("Error is",error);
    });
    alert(" from firebase")
}
submitbtn()
{       
    console.log('Name',this.state.name);
    console.log('Email',this.state.email);
    console.log('subject',this.state.subject);
    console.log('message',this.state.message);
    this.sendtofirebase();
    alert("from submitbtn");
    
}
```

`onSubmit={()=>this.submitbtn()}` If a calls the function like this the data don't add up in the firebase but the alert("from firebase") shows up. If I call the "onSubmit={this.submitbtn()}" like this the data is added to the firebase even before I trigger the submit button. I don't understand why I'm facing this strange behaviour.

Here's the complete contact form code.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
```

import {db} from './firebase';
import { MDBContainer, MDBRow, MDBCol, MDBBtn, MDBIcon,MDBInput } from 'mdbreact';
class ContactForm extends Component
{
constructor(props)
{
super(props);
this.state=
{
name:'',
email:'',
subject:'',
message:'',

```
    }
}



sendtofirebase()
{
    db.collection('contacts').add({
        name:'faizam',
        email:'shdj',
        subject:'hdjshj',
        message:'hjhdjs',
    }).then(()=>{
    alert("Data Sent");
    }).catch((error)=>{
        alert("Error is",error);
    });
    alert(" from firebase")
}
submitbtn()
{       
    console.log('Name',this.state.name);
    console.log('Email',this.state.email);
    console.log('subject',this.state.subject);
    console.log('message',this.state.message);
    this.sendtofirebase();
    alert("from submitbtn");
    
}
render()
{
    return(
    <>
    <div>
        <MDBContainer>
          <MDBRow>
            <MDBCol md="6">
              <form className="form" onSubmit={()=>this.submitbtn()}>
                <p className="h5 text-center mb-4">Contact Me</p>
                <div className="grey-text">
                  <MDBInput label="Your name" icon="user" group type="text" validate error="wrong"
                    success="right" />
                  <MDBInput label="Your email" icon="envelope" group type="email" validate error="wrong"
                    success="right" />
                  <MDBInput label="Subject" icon="tag" group type="text" validate error="wrong" success="right" />
                  <MDBInput type="textarea" rows="2" label="Your message" icon="pencil-alt"  />
                </div>
                <div className="text-center">
                  <MDBBtn  value="submit" type="submit" outline 
                       color="secondary">
                    Send
                    <MDBIcon far icon="paper-plane" className="ml-1" />
                  </MDBBtn>
                </div>
              </form>
            </MDBCol>
          </MDBRow>
        </MDBContainer>
    </div>
     </>
        );
  }
}export default ContactForm;
```

Comment: Does anything happen in the network tab of your devtools or in the console ? It seems weird that it neither calls any of the alert inside of your firebase callbacks

Comment: I've checked the network tab but problem is same if I calls the submitbtn() function without this "()=>"  connection builds up with the firebase but If I call the function like this "()=>this.submitbtn()" firebase don't shows any connection with the app.

Comment: App don't gets any response from the firebase in case of ()=>this.submitbtn but gets the response from the firebase in this.submitbtn().

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is your problem, but it could be your functions have the wrong `this binding`

To fix this you should change:

```
sendtofirebase()
{
    db.collection('contacts').add({
        name:'faizam',
        email:'shdj',
        subject:'hdjshj',
        message:'hjhdjs',
    }).then(()=>{
    alert("Data Sent");
    }).catch((error)=>{
        alert("Error is",error);
    });
    alert(" from firebase")
}
submitbtn()
{       
    console.log('Name',this.state.name);
    console.log('Email',this.state.email);
    console.log('subject',this.state.subject);
    console.log('message',this.state.message);
    this.sendtofirebase();
    alert("from submitbtn");
    
}
```

to:

```
sendtofirebase = () => {
    db.collection('contacts').add({
        name:'faizam',
        email:'shdj',
        subject:'hdjshj',
        message:'hjhdjs',
    }).then(()=>{
    alert("Data Sent");
    }).catch((error)=>{
        alert("Error is",error);
    });
    alert(" from firebase")
}
submitbtn = () => {        
    console.log('Name',this.state.name);
    console.log('Email',this.state.email);
    console.log('subject',this.state.subject);
    console.log('message',this.state.message);
    this.sendtofirebase();
    alert("from submitbtn");
    
}
```

Basically the `someFunction = () => {}` puts the function in the constructor of the class - and this should mean calling `this.someFunction()` is definitely referring to the right this context.

Comment: No, this is also not working, but it works if I calls the without "()=>" but it creates the issue that the function triggers before I even clicks the submit button.